# plsql record type and collection of record type

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a plsql record type mrec and mreclist is collection of that record. I would like to know if it is possible to add each record into mreclist through one statement. Or is there another efficient way to do the same.

```
declare
  type mrec is record ( a varchar2(10),b varchar2(20));
  type mreclist is table of mrec;
  r mrec;
  rlist mreclist;
begin

rlist:=mreclist();

--insert value 

 select 'dummy1','dummy2' into r.a,r.b from dual;

--how to copy the above value into the mreclist with one single statement instead of the following statements. 
 rlist.Extend(1);
 rlist(1).a:=r.a;
 rlist(1).b:=r.b;

select 'dummy3','dummy4' into r.a,r.b from dual;
 rlist.Extend(1);
 rlist(2).a:=r.a;
 rlist(2).b:=r.b;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you looking for a combination of [`BULK COLLECT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) and [`MULTISET` operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm)?

Something like that:

```
declare
  type mrec is record ( a varchar2(10),b varchar2(20));
  type mreclist is table of mrec;
  r mrec;
  rlist mreclist;
  tlist mreclist; -- <-- we need two collections here
begin

 select 'dummy1','dummy2' bulk collect into rlist from dual;
 --     collect initial data into the collection `rlist`      

 select 'dummy3','dummy4' bulk collect into tlist from dual;
 --     collect next data into the other collection `tlist`      

 rlist := rlist multiset union all tlist;
 --     merge `rlist` and `tlist`. Replace the collection `rlist` by the result.
```

I wouldn't say much about the efficiency of such code. It is probably very dependent of your concrete use case. Please note however that at some point, you hold both `rlist` and the result of the union in memory. For large collections this could be prohibitive.

For very basic use cases, you probably only need `BULK COLLECT` and a simple `UNION ALL`:

```
 select * bulk collect into rlist from (
     select 'dummy1','dummy2' from dual
     union all select 'dummy3','dummy4'from dual
   );
```

---

Finally, I would suggest you to take a look at ["Taking Up Collections" *by Steven Feuerstein*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o53plsql-083350.html) for considerations about the result order of multiset operations. Just to quote few words:

> Oracle documentation states that the difference between nested tables and varying arrays is that the data stored in a nested table column does not preserve its order, while that order is preserved in a varying array. Prior to Oracle Database 10g, this distinction did not mean much in the PL/SQL world. Now, with the set operators, the special characteristics of a multiset, or nested table, show themselves quite clearly.